# How to assign name to intermediate whilst pattern matching in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm doing some pattern matching on a colon delimited String as follows:

```
case s:String => s.split(":") match {
  case Array("foo","bar") => ...
  case Array("hello",_,_) => ...
  ...
}
```

How can I rearrange the code to assign a name to the array returned by `s.split(":")`?

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
case s:String => val x = s.split(":") match {
  case Array("foo","bar") => // try to use x here
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
case s:String => s.split(":") match {
  case x @ Array("foo","bar") => ...
  case x @ Array("hello",_,_) => ...
  ...
}
```

Or

```
case s:String =>
  val x = s.split(":")
  x match {
    case Array("foo","bar") => ...
    case Array("hello",_,_) => ...
    case Array(aStr, "bar") => println(aStr.toUpperCase)
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd add a `case Array(f, "bar") => ...` to show that you can assign vals inside matched patterns too.